# How to paste path from string to src img mark in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I paste here a snippet of .cshtml code:

```
@foreach (var element in Model){  
string path = File.Exists("~/Content/Images/" + element.ProductId + ".jpg") ? ("~/Content/Images/" + element.ProductId + ".jpg") : ("~/Content/Images/image_preview.jpg");

    <img src=@path class="pull-left img-thumbnail" height="100" width="100" /> }
```

I don't know why it dosen't work. In path is correct string, but image isn't displayed.

Comment: Could you paste the full path too?

Comment: the `File` class doesn't work with virtual paths.

Comment: Your path here will always be the bit after the `:` and will be output directly to the browser with the `~` prefix. That will not work.

Comment: In the path string is that: "~/Content/Images/image_preview.jpg"

Comment: You need to use the html helper <img src="@Url.Content('')"> since "~/Content" is not a valid url path for the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map your paths to a real file before using the `File.Exists` function. Use the [`Url.Content()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) function to convert the path with `~` prefix to an actual location on the system.

```
@foreach (var element in Model) {
    string testPath = Url.Content("~/Content/Images/" + element.ProductId + ".jpg"));  
    string path = File.Exists(testPath) ? testPath : Url.Content("~/Content/Images/image_preview.jpg");

    <img src="@path" class="pull-left img-thumbnail" height="100" width="100" /> }
```

Comment: I do what you wrote, now i see image "image_preview.jpg" :) but path all time has "image_preview.jpg" string instead "ProductId.jpg" for example "1.jpg"